# Applying a transformation rule on an Image

Tags: image-processing, replacement

I haven't been able to figure out why the following doesn't work:

```
img = Image[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}], "Real"]
img /. {r_, g_, b_} :> 1 - {r, g, b} (* Image left unchanged *)
```

Looking at the full form of **img**, I see that the pixels are stored as lists of three real numbers each, so I don't get why the pattern won't match.

This works though, giving me the "negative" image that I expected from the previous code also:

```
Image[ImageData[img] /. {r_, g_, b_} :> 1 - {r, g, b}]
```

So what's the problem with the first code?

*(Kindly note that the image processing problem that the above code happens to perform is of no interest to me here; I just chose it as an example, so don't misdirect your effort showing how it could be done using library functions. Here, I'm only interested in understanding why the rule application didn't work)*

Comment: Maybe compare `img // Dimensions` to `ImageData[img] // Dimensions` ?

Comment: Yes, I hadn't realised that Image was an atomic type

Comment: Does wrapping an image `ExampleData` returns here -- in another `Image` change anything?

Comment: @BoLe I just did it to convert the image type to "Real".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReplaceAll` doesn't work on atoms.

```
img = Image[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}], "Real"]
AtomQ@img
```

> True

Comment: Thanks, that sort of makes sense to me.

Comment: But you could try `List@@img`, and there are still some problems

Comment: @belarius I didn't understand your point. Trying to replace the Head of an atom doesn't ordinarily do anything, does it? List@@5==5 is True, for example, and so is List@@img==img. I've probably misunderstood the point you're trying to make, so could you please explain?

Comment: @Aky Try `(List @@ Image[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}]] /. {x_, y_, z_, 
      w_} -> x // InputForm) /. RawArray :> List`

Answer (score 9):

[Since version 9](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/vTk8Dy8qqs4/QYC8h0F7nqoJ), `Image` is an atomic object ([`AtomQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html)) and thus it's internal data structures cannot be directly manipulated through `Part` or pattern matching.

Don't let the fact that it has an `InputForm` and `FullForm` with apparent structure confuse you.  This is for convenience only (to make it human readable) and happens with other atomic objects too, such as [`Rational`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rational.html)/[`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html)/etc.  In reality you just can't take an `Image` apart.

Use [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageData.html) and other `Image*` functions to extract data.

Answer (score 5):

`Image[ ]` is a kind of wrapper that contains information about the image: the size, the color map, and of course the `ImageData`. There are lots of functions that deal directly with the image wrapper, for instance, you can accomplish the task you asked using

```
ImageApply[(1 - #) &, img]
```

More generally, you can define your own function `f` and then do: `ImageApply[f, img]`